# Ubuntu 18.04LTS installer does not detect MacOS X on a Mac Mini

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, iso, hfs+, mac-mini

The Ubuntu package looks like a good thing; I would like to install it, but I'm not ready to trash my present operating system.  The Ubuntu installation ISO file is 'not mountable' on my circa 2014 Mac Mini running Hi-Sierra, so I can't view the contents, etc.

When I burned the ISO file to disk, I can boot from that disk, and install the Ubuntu system, but only by deleting the Hi-Sierra filesystem and deleting MacOS X, for in the install process, 'no other op systems are detected'.

The tutorials do not describe the results I am getting. There are hints of a 'mac image iso' download but I can't find it.

Comment: Etcher. http://etcher.io

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos explains how you can make a bootable USB flashdrive for a Mac, but your issue is the installer not sensing the APFS filesystem on the MacMini's drive. Let's confirm that APFS is used instead of the older HFS+ by ... a) Select the device in the Finder. ... b) Choose File > Get Info, or press Command (⌘)-I. ... c) Check the Format shown in the Get Info window. ... Once that's done, please come back here and click on 'edit' above at left in grey, and specify which filesystem you have in your original post.

Comment: The Mac ISO is referenced at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick?_ga=2.90781149.697836061.1530813133-602114795.1530639270

Comment: Use diskutility from macos to shrink your mac partition to create a free space to install Ubuntu on it. Make sure you install grub on the same partition, not on the whole disk. If both are EFI installation, you should be able to boot by using boot selection of macos, cmd+c on bootup I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No "Install Alongside OS X" option when installing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586631/no-install-alongside-os-x-option-when-installing-ubuntu)